# Multivariable calculus Temperature time equation

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm not sure where to begin for this question. I found the partial differential dT/dx and dT/dt equations for the previous step but i'm not sure if that's needed or not. 
$$T(x,y) = T_0+T_1e^{-\lambda x}sin(wt-\lambda x)$$  where $$w=2\pi/365,  \lambda = positive \ constant  $$

Show that  T satisfies $$T_t = kT_{xx} $$ where $$k=w/(2\lambda^2)$$

Comment: Evaluate $\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial t}$ and $\dfrac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2}$, and substitute it in the PDE.

Comment: I found dT/dt and d2T/dx2 and when i multiply k to d2T/dx2, they equal. Is that considered proof that the equation above satisfies? What do you mean substitute it in the PDE? Thanks

Comment: @Aesthetic Yes, all you need to do is show that $T_t$ is equal to $kT_{xx}$.